# Add space between two barchart record in Chartjs and design#2 label set in center same like design#1 sublabel in center

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

[image]

```html
<canvas id="p-myChart" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 450px; width:100% !important "></canvas>

@*parameter multi chart*@
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/chart.umd.js"></script>

<script>
    // setup

    const data = {
        labels: ['LUT', 'DFFs', 'CLBs', 'BRAMs', 'DSPs', 'FLE', 'Metal', 'LUT', 'DFFs', 'CLBs', 'BRAMs', 'DSPs', 'FLE', 'Metal'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Aligned With benchmark',
            data: [1000, 750, 500, 250, 400, 950, 800, 750, 450, 500, 600, 300, 200, 700],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2
        },

        {
            label: 'name here',
            data: [900, 650, 800, 450, 820, 750, 300, 550, 250, 500, 700, 500, 100, 600],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(36, 159, 93,1)',
                'rgba(36, 159, 93, 1)',
                'rgba(241, 180, 94, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(36, 159, 93, 1)',
                'rgba(36, 159, 93, 1)',

                'rgba(248, 174, 71)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(36, 159, 93, 1)',
                'rgba(241, 180, 94, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(36, 159, 93, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
            ],
        },
        ]
    };

    const subLabels = {
        id: 'subLabels',
        afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
            //console.log(chart)
            const { ctx, chartArea: { left, right, top, bottom, width, height } } = chart;


            ctx.save();
            subLabelText('Design#1', width / 4 * 1);
            subLabelText('Design#2', width / 4 * 2);
            //subLabelText('Design#3', width / 4 * 3);


            function subLabelText(text, x) {
                ctx.font = 'border 12px sans-serif';
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.fillText(text, x + left , bottom + 40);

            }

        }
    }

    // config
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {
            barValueSpacing: 20,
            plugins: { legend: { display: false }, },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    bottom: 30
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                    }
                },

               
            }
        },
        plugins: [subLabels]
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart1 = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('p-myChart'),
        config
    );
</script>
@*parameter multi charts*@
```

I want to add space between two records (shown in image) and include label below graph (shown in image).

Comment: I think you could 2 stacked axes and not only one in order to have the title of the aces well center https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html. To add space, maybe a null data for an empty label could help.